# Create variable in view and assign

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I need to create a string variable in my View and assign to a hidden input which is bound to a property on my strongly typed model

I guess it is something like

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.nodelist, new {@value = myVar})
```

however not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use simple html hidden field and keep it's name same as property name.
This works perfectly

```
@{
string val=myVar;
}

<input type="hidden" name="nodelist" value="@val" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to be setting the `@value` attribute on the html helper. That's not how those helpers have been designed to work. They have been designed to bind to the value of the corresponding property on the view model you passed to this view.

So it's as simple as:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.nodelist)
```

and in the controller action rendering this view you would assign the corresponding property on the view model to the desired value:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    MyViewModel model = ...
    model.nodelist = someVariable;
    return View(model);
}
```

If on the other hand this variable is actually a javascript variable then you should obviously use javascript to assign it to the hidden field:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = 'some value';
    $('#nodelist').val(myVar);
</script>
```

or if you are not using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var myVar = 'some value';
    document.getElementById('nodelist').value = myVar;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks but actually I need to add a csharp variable that is generated in the view to a hidden input control that is bound to the model.

Comment: Why would you be generating any variables in a view? That's not how views are supposed to be used. It would be far better to perform this *logic* inside your controller action and assign directly the property to the calculated value.

Comment: I'm using a cms and part of the view is generated from an id in the Model which is used to query nodes within the CMS. I need to get a list of ids of the queried nodes. I know its not how view should be used but this is not an ideal situation

Comment: In this case you could try generating the hidden field like this: `<input type="hidden" name="nodelist" value="@myVar" />`.

Comment: and then how would I get that value into my model property whcih is a string called PollNodes .

Comment: You would `name` your hidden input field accordingly: `<input type="hidden" name="PollNodes" value="@myVar" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Is myVar a javascript variable?

You could assign your hidden field an ID property.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.nodelist, new {@id = "hdnNodeList"})
```

and using javascript or jquery you could do the following

```
$('#hdnNodeList').val(myVar);
```

or if myVar is a C# variable you could try the following (this will render an html output, although you could do it here, its better to assign a value to m.nodelist in your controller if possible)

```
$('#hdnNodeList').val('@myVar');
```